# Search for a text segment using MAX IF in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel book with two columns (text and numbers). The first column has a lot of variables such as `174AXX` that repeat themselves.

I'm now trying to create a third column where I want to find the highest value of the second column (the one that has numbers) and that is associated with the numbers `174`. Meaning that I don't want it to search for the entire word `174AXX`. I want it to go to all variables that start with `174` and search the highest value.

I'm using the Max if function however when I try to use `"*174*"` in the formula it doesn't recognize it.

```
{Max(if(K:K="*174*";L:L))}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you! I have another question. Is there a way of after getting the highest value knowing as well the corresponding variable of third column. It would look something like this: variable AXZ  / 5432. 5432 being the Max value and the AXZ the variable associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the Asterisk doesn't work this way in Arrays.

Instead you can use the find function like to end up with this formula:

```
=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("174",K:K)),L:L))
```

Then press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`